# Python Pandas rolling operation on just a few rows

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe of 1000 rows named `df`. There are two columns: `date` and `log_return`.

```
date          log_return
2014-01-01 .   0.01
2014-01-02 .   0.01
...
2019-02-01 .   0.01 
2019-02-02 .   0.01
2019-02-03 .   0.01
2019-02-04 .   0.01
```

I want to calculate the rolling sum of the past 500 days' log_return only for last three days, which are 2019-02-02, 2019-02-03, and 2019-02-04.

```
df['log_return'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window = 500, min_periods = 500).sum())
```

...will calculate the rolling sum for all dates, which is unnecessary and time-consuming for me. I don't want to do a row filtering after rolling sums are computed for all rows.

Is there a convenient way to do a rolling computation for only a few rows? Because if the dataframe becomes so large, rolling computation for all rows will be more time-consuming.

Comment: Have you tried doing `df.iloc[-3:] = df.iloc[-3:].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window = 500, min_periods = 500).sum())`? This should do the rolling window only on the last 3 rows (assuming sorted by date)

Comment: Don't use apply here. There is absolutely no use for `apply` in this case.

Comment: @KenSyme df.iloc[-3:] will keep only the last three rows when calculating rolling sum, which needs 500 data points for one day.